# Two different applications with the same path (urls.py) - Django

Tags: python, django

In the main urls.py file I did the following:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
path('', include('homepage.urls')),
path('', include('post.urls')),
]
```

Basically I included two urls.py files of two different applications at the same path. How can I make this method work?

Answer (score 0):

This will work given you don't put similar URLs in each file. e.g you can't have `user/` in both `homepage` and `post` apps because if you do, the one in `homepage` will always be called without error.

Comment: I edited my question, hope you can answer